# Separate the key from the value

Tags: php

I set up a new site and want a workaround for the problem.
I have this text in the mysql table

```
{"200":"5","220":"0","65":"4","80":"0","199":"1","197":"1","198":"0","257":"4","223":"0"}
```

I want to fetch the ID and its value by php
For example

```
$id[200] = 5
```

Comment: there is a function called `json_decode` that you can use you know

Comment: `$id = json_decode($json, true); echo $id[200];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert JSON string into an array. Since your JSON string contains numeric indexes so you need to use curly brackets to fetch the values

```
$str = '{"200":"5","220":"0","65":"4","80":"0","199":"1","197":"1","198":"0","257":"4","223":"0"}';
$array = json_decode($str);
echo $array->{'200'};
```

Or you can add second parameter in json_decode as true to fetch the value as normal array

```
$array = json_decode($str,true);
echo $array[200];
```

Here is the live [demo](https://3v4l.org/OaQtU)

Comment: or add `true` as second param for `json_decode` and use output as normal array with numeric keys.